# Accessing Struts2 value stack from inside displayTag column element

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag, valuestack

I want to make the `titleKey` attribute parametric by accessing a property into the Struts 2 Value Stack. So, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<display:table name="myListOfObjects" id="myId" requestURI="/myAction.action" pagesize="10">
    <display:column property="myProperty" titleKey="my.internationalyzed.i18n.key.myProperty.<s:property value='anotherObject.aProperty'/>" />
    ...
```

As you see, I'd want to access a property into an exposed object in my action with

```
<s:property value='anotherObject.aProperty'/>
```

and to put the value into the `titleKey` element.

If I do this, the result is a table column with an unresolved `my.internationalyzed.i18n.key.myProperty` string as title. In other words, the `<s:property>` tag is not interpreted inside the `<display:column>` element.

But if I put the

```
<s:property value='anotherObject.aProperty'/>
```

outside the `<display:table>` element it is correctly resolved and the resulting value is showed on the page, so the property is correctly exposed and valorized.

Do you know how can I access a property exposed in an action from inside the `<display:column>` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSP EL expression inside your non-struts tag, so the expression when looking in the request scope will ask the request to expose the value stack. For example

```
<display:column property="myProperty" titleKey="my.internationalyzed.i18n.key.myProperty.${anotherObject.aProperty}" />
```